# Overide a class imported in a imported module

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a module, which uses a class which it imports from somewhere else. I want to change the class used by the imported module, to a class I have defined in my program. To illustrate:

**a.py module**

```
class kdtree:
    def get(self):
        return 5
```

**b.py module**

```
from a import kdtree
def execute():
    tree = kdtree()
    print(tree.get())
```

**c.py module which will be executed**

```
import b
b.execute()
```

I do not want to modify a.py or b.py, but I want to modify `kdtree` to use my own `kdtree` class in c.py. Is this possible in python?

Comment: Is everything in your folder? If not show us the folder structure.

Comment: @KlausD. no, they are all in different folders

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the `kdtree` attribute of the module `b` with a different one in `c.py`:

```
# c.py
import b
class kdtree:
    def get(self):
        return 10
b.kdtree = kdtree
b.execute()
```